# Duplicate name/signature linking issue with OpenSSL library

Tags: linux, linker, openssl, ld

When I build my executable, I'm running into an issue where I have an object file that has a symbol with the same name/signature as one of the OpenSSL functions in libcrypto (SHA_Update). I guess I have two issues here:

1.) I'm surprised that the linker doesnt complain that there are multiple definitions of that symbol.

2.) The executable I built calls into HMAC_Update (which will call SHA_Update). However, it calls the SHA_Update that was defined in one of my object files as opposed to OpenSSL's SHA_Update.

Can anyone shed some light on this? libcrypto is dynamically linked with my executable.

I thought it may be an issue with weak linking, where the openssl function was weakly linked and the one in my object file was strong linked, which would explain all of this (since the linker wouldnt complain about multiple definitions and the strong linked one would clobber the weak linked one, but i dont see any sort of reference to weakly linked symbols with objdump or readelf in either of the files).

Comment: The linker sees the same name and combines them. You can use C++ namespaces to avoid the clash; or you can rename your `SHA_Update` to something like `My_SHA_Update`. You can also provide a wrapper shared object around the *static* version of OpenSSL. In your wrapper, be sure to specify `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` so it hides all the symbols from OpenSSL. It was probably a bad idea to choose the same name as a function from a well known library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. The code base in question was already there before I was asked to look at it...but yeah i think it was a _terrible_ idea to use the same name for the two.